# Canning Vegan White Sauce

Tags: canning

I have a white sauce recipe similar to Alfredo that I made up and a vegan friend of mine and I recently made it but substituted all vegan products and it turned out fantastic.  I was wondering if it would be possible to can said recipe.  I looked up canning Alfredo and because of the dairy it seems it's not possible, but I was wondering since there is no dairy if it were possible to can and if so how long it would last?

**UPDATE**
I figured I should include the ingredients. So the recipe contains:

- Vegan Butter
- Flour
- Soy Milk
- Vegan Parmesan Cheese
- Onion
- Garlic
- Kosher Salt
- Black Pepper
- Basil

Comment: How is the sauce cooked?  Regular Alfredo is just melted, not cooked, but yours looks like more of a white sauce?  Asking because the cooking temperature relates to your ability to process it for canning.

Answer (score 2):

There are no current safe recommendations for home canning oils/fats as it’s considered unsafe for a verity of reasons. Although you are using alternatives for dairy many will still have high fat and oil content that can cause botulism which is a type of food poisoning that can lead to death. I would recommend that if you make a large amount of this sauce to freeze it instead and to not exceed storing it longer than a couple months. I know this can be really disappointing considering that it’s a vegan sauce and you probably would like the ease of “reach and pour” but I wouldn’t risk it. Please use your own discretion. https://www.healthycanning.com/fat-and-oil-in-home-canning/